# Select row from table where column value is subset of value passed in stored procedure

Tags: mysql, sql, database, stored-procedures

I have a table with columns and data something like this

```
+------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| name | search_name             | client_name | display_name |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
| J&J  | J&J | Johnson & Johnson | Janssen     | J&J          |
+------+-------------------------+-------------+--------------+
```

now i want to create a stored procedure that will pass a string lets say **"Johnson & Johnson company" or "J&J company"** and storproc should match the passed string with all the columns data and if any of the column value is subset of passed value so storproc should select that row or count of row(anything would be fine).

to be more precise if I pass "J&J company" in storproc and name column contain "J&J"(which is a subset of passed value) so storproc should return above row or count of row(anything would be fine).

PS : this is just a sample data original table contains more that 47000 rows so I can't do this in php level.

I have to do just opposite of 'LIKE' operator in mysql where in LIKE you pass a subset of string and table contains superset but in my case I have to pass a superset string and if table columns(any one) contains a subset that row should be returned.

Hope I have elaborated the problem enough, any help would be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I took the concat from Gordon's answer, but I think this is what you're looking to do?

```
BEGIN
    SELECT *
    FROM tableName
    WHERE @parameter LIKE concat('%', search_name, '%')
END
```

WHERE @parameter is your passed in string something like 'J&J Company'  and search_name is your column name.

Answer (score 1):

You can still do this with `like`, by concatenating the wildcards to the passed in parameter:

```
where name like concat('%', @parameter, '%') or
      searchname like concat'%', @parameter, '%') or
      . . .
```